Recat Native Video Zooming
I am trying to add video zooming feature in react-native-video
But the video is playing but I can't see it. only hearing the audio with a full red color screen
Please, someone help me to fix this.
I used the package react-native-zoom-reanimated
this is the code
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import Video from 'react-native-video';
import ZoomView from 'react-native-zoom-reanimated';

const VideoPlayer = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const videodata = route.params.video;
  const playRate = 1;

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ZoomView style={styles.zoomView} minScale={1} maxScale={4}>
        <Video
          source={{ uri: videodata.HLS_url }}
          style={styles.video}
          resizeMode="contain"
          rate={parseFloat(playRate) || 1}
          controls={true}
        />
      </ZoomView>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  zoomView: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor:'red',
  },
  video: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
});

export default VideoPlayer;

